# How can I exclude attachment content when searching in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, search

I've noticed that when I do a search in Outlook 2010, Outlook considers it a match if some of the terms I'm searching for are in a message attachment.  I'd like to disable this.

When I search for terms in my email archive, I don't want to see something listed where some of the terms I'm searching for are in an attachment. I only want to see results where everything I'm searching for is in the message itself (or its headers).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Outlook searches all items in the folder. You can refine your search by using advanced options on the `Search` tab (appears when you click in the search box).

[image]

Clicking the `More` button gives you specific fields to search in.

[image]

Even faster, if you know the name of the field you can type it directly into the search box; i.e. `subject:foo` `content:foo`. This will only search the fields you specify. FYI, `content` is the body of the message. There are no spaces between the field, the `:` and the search term. Place a single space between multiple fields to be searched (like the image below).

[image]

Comment: Is there something I can type into the search box to exclude attachment content?  Something like "-attachment"? That would be more practical than specifying content+from+subject.

Comment: You can use `hasattachment:no`, but it excludes messages with attachments from the search results. I've not been able to find anything which will stop it from searching within the attachments, yet include the message in the search. Here is more information about [Learn to narrow your search criteria for better searches in Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-HA010238831.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use content:foo. That will narrow the scope of the search to just the content and ignore matches in the attachment.

Comment: Note that this idea had been suggested above. Also, the original question specified that I'd like to search headers, too, not just the body of the message.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but this "feature" still drives me nuts. In addition to @CharlieRB 's ideas, I found this article: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/exclude-attachment-content-when-searching that lists a few more search methods, including:

```
keywords NOT attachment:"keywords"
```

which, as far as I can tell excludes any email with the term in the attachment, which isn't exactly what I want, but I can follow it up with

```
keywords AND attachment:"keywords"
```

to get the missing stuff. The only bit we don't really want is

```
attachment:"keywords" NOT keywords
```

but I can't think of a way to combine the 1st & 2nd cases without including the 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

The attachment contents seem to be bundled into the Message field. The only way we can think of is to export all the attachments from relevant messages to a One folder, then search the files in Win OS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).